# Can not acces Magento API log file. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b7e549729324

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento-2.1.9, http-error-500

We are trying to access via rest-API and search orders via `[increment_id]`, so we are using this GET:

```
<web>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[increment_id][value]=068550002
```

Is this line correct? As an answer I get:

> {
>       "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b7e549729324"
>   }

[image]

But I can't access `var/report/api`, there isn't any folder created.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: try with this `'{"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"increment_id","value":"000000106","condition_type": "eq"}]}]}}';`

Comment: Where should I replace? 

rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[increment_id][value]=068550002

Like this?

rest/V1/orders?'{"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"increment_id","value":"000000106","condition_type": "eq"}]}]}}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call is misformatted. It should look like this:

`<web>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=086160005&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`